# Forwarding API calls from a sub dominos to static IP address(from ISP)

Tags: api, subdomain, redirect, static-ip-address

I currently have an API setup at 
http://public_static_IP:5000/api/parameters (POST requests).

I have bought a domain from **NameCheap** and hosted in **GoDaddy**, also added SSL from **Cloudflare**.

I have created a URL Redirect of a subdomain(http://www.web.domain.com) to http://public_static_IP:5000, which is a webpage and it is working fine.

I did the same with another subdomain(http://www.api.domain.com) to API endpoint which is an only POST request, so when I add all parameters and send a post request to this subdomain it is giving **Method not allowed**.

This is very important for us as users will always be using this API service and we don't want any downtime(sometimes ISP will be down), if ISP is down we want to temporarily route to some cloud service(AWS or Google Cloud) without asking users to change their base URL always.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share reverse proxy configuration ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan sorry didn't configure a reverse proxy.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Thanks I have configured it and working fine.